# Error: Not ready to parse. Missing Content-Type?

Tags: node.js, express

I'm driving a node.js/express.js app with curl. The curl command:
`curl -X PUT -i -T LICENSE.txt localhost:9981/v1/test/bucket/some-object -s`

errors, saying content-type should be present. Content-type of 'text/plain' does not work. In fact, the only content-type that works seems to be: `Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=---something`

However! What should be the boundary, if I'm only putting some text file? The curl command hangs because, I assume, the boundary cannot be made up.

Now, this curl command works: `curl localhost:9981/v1/test/container/some-object -X PUT -F "file=@/opt/nedge/README.md"` But this is not quite what I want, because I don't want to specify `file=@`

And the last piece of the question is, the node.js code that is being run. It is the example busboy, the first example from their github: https://github.com/piousbox/busboy

My question is: either how to specify the correct boundary with curl, or how to make busboy (or node.js streams overall) accept content-type other than `multipart/form-data`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Busboy only processes multipart/form-data (generally when at least one of the fields is a file) or application/x-www-form-urlencoded requests (no files). If you need to process a 'text/plain' or other type of request, then just add your own middleware before your regular form processing middleware. Something like this perhaps:

```
// ....

app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  if (!req.headers['content-type'])
    return next(new Error('Bad request'));
  if (req.headers['content-type'].indexOf('text/plain') === 0) {
    // read from `req` here with req.read() or req.on('data', ...), etc.
  } else
    next();
});

// ....
```

Comment: Is this the same as saying, "do not use busboy use stream API of the plain old express requests"?

Comment: If you're expecting non-form submissions, then yes, you have to handle the request yourself.